# Redirect two page on single button click with POST data using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jQuery redirect plugin and I want to redirect to two pages at a time on a single button click with post data. Using below code single redirect is working. Multiple redirections is not working.

```
function pdf_redirect() {
var ro_no = $('#addNew input[name=ro_no]').val();

//alert(ro_no);

$.redirect("letters/Release_Order_letter.php",
{
    ro_no: ro_no
}, "POST", "_blank");


$.redirect("letters/tax_invoice.php",
{
    ro_no: ro_no
},"POST", "_blank");

}
```

Comment: Redirect to two pages at the same time?

Comment: Means open two different pages in different two tabs on button click with POST data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use below working code:

```
<button id="redirect" >redirect me</button>
<div id="inset_form"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#redirect").click(function(){

var value = 10;
$('#inset_form').html('
<form action="letters/Release_Order_letter.php" name="form" method="post" style="display:none;"  target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="ro_no" value="' + value + '" />
</form>');
document.forms['form'].submit();
var delayInMilliseconds = 1;
setTimeout(function() {
  //your code to be executed after 1 second

$('#inset_form').html('
<form action="letters/tax_invoice.php" name="form" method="post" style="display:none;"  target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="ro_no" value="' + value + '" />
</form>');
document.forms['form'].submit();
}, delayInMilliseconds);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with window.open to open two different pages in two different tabs. Please try below code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function hi(){
    alert("hi");

    window.open("letters/Release_Order_letter.php");
    window.open("letters/tax_invoice.php");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onClick="hi();" value="click">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, for your replay, But I have to send data(Parameter) by POST

Comment: you can pass the parameter as a query like tax_invoice.php?param=$ro_no

Comment: I want send parameter using POST not GET.

Comment: are you doing anything using post method?? Please explain in detail